# Information Gene HBA2

Tags: bioinformatics

Gene : HBA2? hemoglobin alpha 2 (*Homo sapiens*)

I don't find any tissues (or organs) in which the expression of this gene is strongest? What is the size of the gene (promoter off) encoding this sequence?

Comment: Hello, where have you tried to find information on HBA2?

Comment: On the NCBI site, but the site is rich in information and like I started in bioinformatics...

Comment: you could also use wikipedia as a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin,_alpha_2 for many genes this will give you already a good overview and links to sources

Comment: [GeneCards](http://www.genecards.org/) is also a decent site for these type of information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't find the size of the promoter, I know the size of the gene is 864 bases but with the promoter and i need is size without promoter

Comment: Gene size will not include the promoter. The main reason is that the exact location of the promoter is not defined (or defined arbitrarily).

Comment: not sure that I understand what is going on here, but the HBA2 gene product is 142 amino acids which corresponds to 426 nt plus a stop codon makes it 429 nt

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you "started in bioinformatics", so perhaps you might feel more comfortable taking such an approach to better characterize where the promoter for HBA2 might be.

As @Bitwise mentioned in his comment, "the promoter" is not a well defined region. Often times "we" take the promoter of a gene to be some arbitrary (2-4) kilobytes upstream from the TSS. With more high throughput data coming online (especially from [ENCODE](http://genome.ucsc.edu/ENCODE/)), we are starting to get a better picture of where the *functional* regulatory elements of genes might be.

By combining data from several different high-throughput assays across a variety of cell types, the human genome has been [segmented](http://uswest.ensembl.org/info/docs/funcgen/regulatory_segmentation.html) into broad regions of interest. You might start by looking for where the "Predicted promoter region including transcription start site" segment is for HBA2.

I'd also take a closer look at the [DNase-seq data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNase-Seq) in this "promoter region" across as many cell lines as they have processed for you to look for regions that are differentially occupied in hopes of identifying more precisely which parts in the promoter region might be important for the gene's expression (this would, of course, require you to connect DNAseq data with gene expression (RNA-seq) data).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answers that helps me a lot


I determined that the gene HBA2 had four SNPs but to find  how many allele phenotypically it is I do not know if I should take the column'' Allele origin " or the column dbSNP allele Thank you again